# Mailgun stats don't add up

Tags: json, api, mailgun

I'm trying to make sense of the mailgun stats returned from the API, and the numbers simply don't add up.

I'm making the following call

```
$stats = $mg->get('example.com/stats/total', array(
    'event' => array('accepted', 'delivered', 'failed', 'stored'),
    'duration' => '1m',
    "resolution" => "month"
));
```

And get this result (re-formatted to JSON for easier reading)

```
{
    'accepted' : {
        'incoming' : 200,
        'outgoing' : 458,
        'total' : 658
    },
    'delivered' : {
        'smtp' : 399,
        'http' : 0,
        'total' : 399
    },
    'failed' : {
        'temporary' : {
            'espblock' : 0
        },
        'permanent' : {
            'suppress-bounce' : 0,
            'suppress-unsubscribe' : 0,
            'suppress-complaint' : 0,
            'bounce' : 0,
            'total' : 0
        }
    },
    'stored' : {
        'total' : 0
    }
}
```

Now, what I don't understand is this: Shouldn't the sum of delivered messages + failed messages + stored messages be greater than or equal to the number of accepted outgoing messages? In this example they are quit significantly lower, and that doesn't seem to make sense to me.

I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, accepted outgoing messages are equal to the sum of delivered messages + bounces messages.

Try using the Date (something like start/end) rather than the duration/resolution.

That's what I used in my cron, and it worked. You can go to the dashboard of Mailgun to check and compare with your results

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change anything for me: Different time range, but I still get 771 outgoing accepted, 696 delivered, 2 temp fails, 1 permanent fail, leaving 72 completely disappearing. I might open a ticket with them ...

Comment: Almost 10% disappearing, it's a bit weird. I remember when I used my cron, I had only 0,25% of disappearing messages, with a last state of 'accepted'. The ticket might be the solution ;)

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I might have misunderstood something that might be common knowledge ..